# Can't open shared drive after disconnecting vpn

Tags: windows-xp, vpn, network-shares, samba, authentication

I use a VPN to connect to my office network.  On my local network I have another WinXP machine that shares a printer and a few shared folders.  While I'm connected to my work VPN, I can access the shared printer and folders on the other machine just fine, and vice versa.  Once I disconnect the VPN, I can't access the local machine any more, and the other machine can't access my machine.  The network itself seems ok - I can ping the other machine, get to the internet, and get on to a web server shared by the other machine, but I can't get to the shared folders or printer.  If I reconnect to the VPN, my access is restored.  I'm guessing this is some sort of authentication thing, but I don't know what.  Any ideas?

**Update**

This problem is bothering me again, so here's an update.  Depending on when I first access the WinXP machine, I either have this problem, or the opposite problem.  After a reboot, if I (for example) print, then connect to the VPN, I can't access the machine while on the VPN.  If after a reboot I connect to the VPN, then print, I can't access the machine off the VPN.  In both cases, if I enable/disable the VPN again, I can access the machine again.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try to change your network group to group X  then reboot. after, return the name of your group back to where it was. ALSO with your vpn . you have to check that you are not useing the remote gateway. This in effect uses your vpn like a proxy server for ALL of your networking needs. If you can ping your local computer then maybe you could try a direct connect to the computer in a run command IE.  \\192.168.1.10
this should bring you up to the share area for files and printers, double click the printer that you want. If it asks for a user and password use an administrators.

EDIT: Further thoughts....your local computers can connect to you While you are connected to your vpn,and when your not connected .. you can't/they can't....that is strange....haveing all in the same group and re run your network connections wizard and set up the proper file sharing ..take a look at your firewall see that it is OFF or at least not effecting the local intranet.